# Connecting to mysql via odbc in a 64 bit system

Tags: mysql, odbc, 64-bit

I have installed the community server on my computer but for some reason i keep on getting this error

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;Database=smsserver;
User=root;Password=123456;Option=3;

ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

This is my connection string

`Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;Database=smsserver;
User=root;Password=123456;Option=3;`

I have not done anything really,i just installed the community edition and tried to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;
Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;
```

[Data origin](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by downloading the 32 bit odbc connector and installing and doing the same for he 64 bit.

I then used my original string and worked.The answer also given above

`Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;
Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;`

also worked.

Comment: Whats the point in copying the answer I have given to you and repost it as own answer! Can you not even read that is exactly the same code? Nobody is paid on SO to give answers and the only way to say thank you is to vote or accept an answer. People like you waste members time and shows no care for the time that has been spent to try help them.

Comment: And what you should laugh about? The answer you have given to yourself contains exactly the same string I posted. May be you should laugh about yourself.

Comment: I am on windows 8 and for  odbc to work you need to install the 32 bit connector that installs both the ansi and unicode drivers. You kinda left that bit out and you assume i havent been to connection strings website even before you answered the question. The only reason i accepted your answer is to allow you delude yourself further into taking and demanding credit for the google pasted half answer.

Comment: Im using Windows 10. I installed MysqlServer 5.7 in my system. and ODBC driver 5.3 ANSI. But i couldn't connect to DB. :( ...

Answer (score 0):

in many cases, installing the redists ([vcredist_x64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU_4/vcredist_x64.exe)) or ([vcredist_x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/C/5BC5DBB3-652D-4DCE-B14A-475AB85EEF6E/vcredist_x86.exe)) solves this issue.

> i am wondering why it is not mentioned any where on the website?